Amplifier design using MOSFET
In designing an amplifier, I can have gain and make the MOSFET work in sat region, but the problem there is the \$V_{ds}\$ and \$V_{gs}\$ voltage was not designed.
How can I make a more precise design? How should I select the Q point?
In the first picture the signal is not biased.
DataSheet File



You said that Vds and Vgs are not what you want. So what values do you want for them?

The problem here is , Vgs values under 4.5v is not mentionet in the datasheet. Due to this i could not made the biasing calculations and design in my sheet. But if I straight connect Vcc to drain and source to the ground and set the Vgs value as i want in simulation , i can found the Id and so the gm value in this way. Im not correct if im doing this right

Datasheet clearly mentions Vgs(th) from 2 to 4V.

Assuming Vgs is 3 , how can i find the value of Id for Vgs = 4v and Vds = 2v

Have you tried what G36 suggested in one of your previous thread?

Yes problem is not having gain with an mosfet but the operating point. It determines the values of the resistors. Let the design have 4 gain so the Resitors Rd=4K and Rs = K equation gives and gain around 4. But to determine the K i need to set the biasing point. It is also important in designing feedback mechanism

Im talking about single mos for now

So the method i mentioned "  But if I straight connect Vcc to drain and source to the ground and set the Vgs value as i want in simulation , i can found the Id and so the gm value in this way. " is correct or not ?
