MOSFET feedback mechanism
I made an simple feedback circuit. R2 and R3 is voltage divider there so I'm setting them sufficiently big values. But in this setup, it works with 2N7002 and not IRFZ44N (gain is way less then I set or it completely not working). Trying different values I found out setting lower values of resistances with same ratio makes is more suitable. Why is that and why I cant set there bigger values of resistances, what makes the difference?



I also found out that when i set VCC lower than 15V , IRFZ44N starts to give less gain and further doesnt work again.

I guess it is because they are power mosfets and have bigger values of gate charges to open but not sure

I tried IRFZ44N  and it's working fine in my simulation with the gain of 3 which matches my calculation.

It doesn't work with Vcc around 10v on me , in the picture Vcc is at 20v

It's all about biasing. It should work if you bias properly and probably reduce the input voltage.

How could i correct it ?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716414/amplifier-design-using-mosfet

Can you also check this then ?

Try R2=50k and R3=100k but this would reduce the gain to 1.5 V/V as the gain is 1+R2/R3.

Still not working i do add an picture to question

Do not change anything in your orginal circuit except Vdd to 10V and R3 to 100k ohms.

Yes it does work now can you help me about biasing mosfets in real life ? I actually can design and solve problems according to Razavi's lectures but in real life there is no constant Vto etc.

The threshold voltage for an IRFZ44 is much higher than a 2N7002 so a design without proper biasing is not likely to work with both parts.

I notice i should care biasing but one of the purposes of this design is to make ampilifier undependent from supply , load etc. I can not calculate the q point looking into datasheet.

@alidemir why can't you calculate operating point?

If I get the value of Vgs that supplies the Id i use for my calculations no problem. The problem is to match Id and Vgs values. For example there is no 2mA Id value in datasheet.
